# bind( ) no JavaScript / React - Dúvida

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

por que eu preciso, necessariamente, fazer o bind() de uma função dentro de um construtor? tipo:

```
constructor (props){

   super(props);

   this.funcao = this.funcao.bind(this);
}
```

Não daria pra fazer esse bind() sem o construtor?

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer no render, mas, como o render sempre é chamado quando ocorre alguma atualização, por razões de desempenho, o ideal é fazer no construtor. Você também poderia usar uma arrow function, mas, acabaria caindo no problema acima. Um exemplo usando arrow function

```js
class Home extends Component {
  onCardPress = (message) => {
    alert(message)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Card
          onCardPress={this.onCardPress}
          message="Hello world!"
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class Card extends Component {
  onClick = () => {
    const { message, onCardPress } = this.props;
    onCardPress(message);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.8}
        onPress={this.onClick}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Aqui tem um texto que explica melhor como o bind funciona

https://medium.com/shoutem/react-to-bind-or-not-to-bind-7bf58327e22a

Comment: Obrigado Bins, se puder olha minha resposta acima... e me corrija por favor

Answer (score 0):

Então não teria problema de fazer assim?

```
export default class App extends Component{


state = {
    texto: ''
}

this.alteraStatus = this.alteraStatus.bind(this);

alterarStatus = (t)=>{
    this.setState({texto: this.state.texto = t});
}

render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder='Qual é o seu nome?' onChangeText={this.mudarTexto}></TextInput>

            <Text style={styles.texto}>{this.state.texto}</Text>

        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Creio que o seu código acima não funcionaria por conta que está fora de um contexto.
E se o bind estivesse no contexto render pode ser chamado muitas vezes, pois isso ele deveria vir no contrutor.
Sobre o bind encontrei um link que pode te ajudar a entender melhor. https://tableless.com.br/react-this-bind-so-sei-que-assim/